# How to Work With Uri.encodeComponent in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: string, flutter, dart, uri

I am working with a customized webview, there I need to pass a url as ***String***.
In this url, I need to pass some query parameter, for various reason, I can't pass'm as body rather url;
Problem is, one of my parameter contain special character such as `$` , `\` , `&`. To use the parameter as string I used `Uri.encodeComponent` to encode the param, but I am facing a strange problem.

if I make the url using `Uri.encodeComponent` , the url is not working

```
url = "soemthing.php?acc_token=" + Uri.encodeComponent(str);
```

But, If I print the output, and make the url manually, the url work just find.

Full Scenario ->

```
var str = await GetUserLocalStorage().accessToken();
//str = "\$3d\#"

var token =  Uri.encodeComponent(str);
//token = %243d%23
//this maybe not exactly same, using it for simulation

print(token);

url = "soemthing.php?acc_token=" + token; //this is not working

//tried token.toString() too!

url = "soemthing.php?acc_token=" + "%243d%23" // this is working

url = "soemthing.php?acc_token=" + Uri.encodeComponent(str);
//This is not working
```

Comment: `void main() {
final baseUri = Uri.parse('http://example.com/some/path/something.php');
final foo = baseUri.replace(queryParameters: {'acc_token': r'foo\bar$spam&eggs'});
print(foo);
}`

Comment: unfortunately this is not working for me, cause the url needs to be string, I can't pass the foo without .toString() , and if I used .toString(), the problem's remain same!!
By the way, thanks a lot for the reply!

Comment: i mean what is the difference if you do: `void main() {
final foo = Uri.parse('http://example.com/something.php')
.replace(queryParameters: {'acc_token': r'$3d#'});
print(foo.toString());
print("http://example.com/something.php?acc_token=" + "%243d%23");` ?
}`

Comment: Two of them return the same output,  don't get me wrong, the problem acting strange.
Even two of them are same, if I use foo.toString(), this is not working, but if  print the foo, and later copy it and use the output as static url (url = output // not foo.toString()) , working just fine.

Comment: it is not possible, there is no magic: you have some errors somewhere else, btw you can also use `final foo1 = Uri.http('example.com', 'something.php', {'acc_token': r'$3d#'});
print(foo1.toString());`

Comment: I found the Problem, I was using async's await to get the access_token,and I pass the value without waiting for it, so I was getting null without my knowledge.
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: sure, your welcome, as i said: "there is no magic" ;-)